# Efficiently find closest points that do not share "neighbours"

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of points, where the distance between them is Manhattan distance, and for every point `p` a `neighbour` is defined as any point lower than `p` (on the `y-axis`) that is within or on the southwest and southeast diagonals extending down from `p`; how can we efficiently enumerate for any given `p` the closest neighbours that do not share other neighbours (that are farther from `p`)?

For example, for the point `p` below, we would want only `a` and `b` (they are closest to `p`) because `c` and `d` are `neighbours` of both `p` and `a` and are farther from `p` than `a`, but `b` does not share neighbours with `p`.

```
    p
   a \
  /   b
 /c d/ \
```

I would prefer up to `O(n)` *preprocessing* time and space. I thought of preprocessing all the relevant diagonals so that given a point, we can iterate along each diagonal from top to bottom where the first encountered such `neighbour`, would stop the iteration and indicate a "triangle" to mark off, where any other point in such a triangle would not need to be reviewed, but I'm not sure how to implement such a triangular "marking," and it seems like there may be too many subdivisions to be efficient.

Could this problem be related to convex hull?

Comment: In your diagram, isn't d actually closer to p than b because it is manhatten distance? (p,d) would be (0,3) and (p,b) would be (2,2), so to d the distance is 3 and to b the distance is 4. So d is just excluded because it is also a neighbour of a while b isn't? Why just O(n) preprocessing? Wouldn't O(n log n) also be ok?

Comment: @maraca `d` is reachable from `a`, hence it is not included. `O(n log n)` preprocessing would be OK, just not preferable.